# C correct usage of getenv("XXX") return string

Tags: c, if-statement

I am writing a program in C as below

```
char *msg = "Do you want to overwrite existing data in config file? (Y/n) [n] : ";
// if (!fexists(CONFFILE)) {                                            // Doesnt work if uncommented
//     msg = "Do you want to save data to config file? (Y/n) [n] : ";   // Doesnt work if uncommented
// }                                                                    // Doesnt work if uncommented

struct arguments arguments;

arguments.a = "vala";
arguments.b = "valb";
arguments.c = "valc";

argp_parse (&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);

printf("%s", msg);
char ans = getchar();
if ((ans == 'y') || (ans == 'Y')) {
    CONFIG cfg = {a, b, c};
    create_config(cfg); //The function that stops working
    if (!fexists(CONFFILE)) {
        printf("Saved credentials to config file.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Err: Unable to save " CONFFILE)
    }
} else {
    printf("Not saving credentials to config file.\n");
}
```

fexists(), create_config() are confirmed to be working as intended.

```
bool fexists(char *fname) {
    struct stat buffer;   
    return (stat (fname, &buffer) == 0);
}

int create_config(struct config cfg) {
    struct json_object *jsonobj = json_object_new_object();
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "api", json_object_new_string(cfg.api));
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "key", json_object_new_string(cfg.key));
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "domain", json_object_new_string(cfg.domain));
    return json_object_to_file_ext(CONFFILE, jsonobj, JSON_C_TO_STRING_SPACED | JSON_C_TO_STRING_PRETTY);
}
```

create_config() [and the program] **works as intended *if the above `if` statement is commented* but stops working *if uncommented.***

Is there any mistake in my code?
What is the solution for this?

EDIT: minimal program to reproduce the issue

```
// Compile with gcc -ljson-c
// libjson-c-dev is required
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <json-c/json.h>
#include <json-c/json_object.h>
#include <json-c/json_util.h>

struct config {
    char *a;
    char *b;
    char *c;
};

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define CONFFILE strcat(getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"), "/.conf.json")
#else
    #define CONFFILE strcat(getenv("HOME"), "/.conf.json")
#endif

int create_config(struct config cfg) {
    struct json_object *jsonobj = json_object_new_object();
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "a", json_object_new_string(cfg.a));
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "b", json_object_new_string(cfg.b));
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "c", json_object_new_string(cfg.c));
    int retval = json_object_to_file_ext(CONFFILE, jsonobj, JSON_C_TO_STRING_SPACED | JSON_C_TO_STRING_PRETTY);
    printf("Err: %s\n", json_util_get_last_err());
    return retval;
}

bool fexists(char *fname) {
    struct stat buffer;   
    return (stat (fname, &buffer) == 0);
}


int main(){
    char *msg = "Do you want to create conffile? (y/n) ";
    // if (!fexists(CONFFILE)) {                                   // Comment these to fix
    //     msg = "Do you want to overwrite conffile? (y/n) ";      // Comment these to fix
    // }                                                           // Comment these to fix
    printf("%s", msg);
    if (((a=getchar()) == 'y') || (a == 'Y')){
        char *a = "vala";
        char *b = "valb";
        char *c = "valc";
        struct config cfg = {a, b, c};
        printf("%d", create_config(cfg));
    }
}
```

***libjson-c-dev is required to compile the program***

EDIT2: error message is now printed.
`Err: json_object_to_file: error opening file /home/user/.conf.json/.conf.json: No such file or directory`

Comment: And for future questions please take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). While in this case it's possible to ***guess*** what the problem is, that could not always be done. Please give us more details.

Comment: the issue is not related to leftover \n newline character as the program runs as intended when if statement is commented out. kindly repoen the question as its not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer

Comment: Then you need to show us a [mre], tell us exactly which of the `if` statements are causing the problem, what the actual problem is (what do you really mean with "stops working"?), and what the value of `ans` really is.

Comment: Also `ans` is 'y' which is the intended value when i run  debugger. so the problem is definitely something else.

Comment: About the duplicate, I'm sorry about that. For some reason I misread your code. I've reopened it. But you still need to tell us what you mean with "stops working". What happens? What is supposed to happen? And a [mre] is really crucial for us to be able to properly help you.

Comment: Stops working means the CONFFILE is not created and no other error output is produced except for `Err: Unable to save " CONFFILE`

Comment: Please add these important information to your question by [edit]ing it. This is not a forum.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `create_config()` while debugging?

Comment: Ret Val is `-1` when if statement is uncommented and `0` otherwise.
Error is `Err: json_object_to_file: error opening file /home/user/.conf.json/.conf.json: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does the directory `/home/user/.conf.json` exist?

Comment: On another but very important note, `strcat(getenv("..."), "/.conf.json")` will modify the string returned by [`getenv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv). And that leads to *undefined behavior* and shouldn't be done. Not to mention that there's no safety if `getenv` fails and returns a null pointer. You need to make it work some other way without modifying the string returned by `getenv`.

Comment: yeah thats the answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caught the issue...

It wasn't related to if loop. Instead it was the incorrect usage of getenv("XXX")

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define CONFFILE strcat(getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"), "/.conf.json")
#else
    #define CONFFILE strcat(getenv("HOME"), "/.conf.json")
#endif
```

is wrong as the value returned by getenv("XXX") gets modified and further calls to getenv will return incorrect value.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    char* confdir = getenv("LOCALAPPDATA");
#else
    char* confdir = getenv("HOME");
#endif
 char* conffile = malloc(sizeof(confdir) + sizeof("/.conf.json") + 1);
strcpy(conffile, confdir);
strcat(conffile, "/.conf.json");

// And use conffile variable instead of CONFFILE macro.
```

So the example code will change to

```
// Compile with gcc -ljson-c
// libjson-c-dev is required
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <json-c/json.h>
#include <json-c/json_object.h>
#include <json-c/json_util.h>

struct config {
    char *a;
    char *b;
    char *c;
};

int create_config(struct config cfg, char* conffile) {
    struct json_object *jsonobj = json_object_new_object();
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "a", json_object_new_string(cfg.a));
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "b", json_object_new_string(cfg.b));
    json_object_object_add(jsonobj, "c", json_object_new_string(cfg.c));
    int retval = json_object_to_file_ext(conffile, jsonobj, JSON_C_TO_STRING_SPACED | JSON_C_TO_STRING_PRETTY);
    printf("Err: %s\n", json_util_get_last_err());
    return retval;
}

bool fexists(char *fname) {
    struct stat buffer;   
    return (stat (fname, &buffer) == 0);
}


int main(){
    ifdef _WIN32
        char* confdir = getenv("LOCALAPPDATA");
    #else
        char* confdir = getenv("HOME");
    #endif
    char* conffile = malloc(sizeof(confdir) + sizeof("/.conf.json") + 1);
    strcpy(conffile, confdir);
    strcat(conffile, "/.conf.json");

    char *msg = "Do you want to create conffile? (y/n) ";
     if (!fexists(conffile)) {                                   // Now this works
         msg = "Do you want to overwrite conffile? (y/n) ";      // Now this works
     }                                                           // Now this works 

    printf("%s", msg);
    if (((a=getchar()) == 'y') || (a == 'Y')){
        char *a = "vala";
        char *b = "valb";
        char *c = "valc";
        struct config cfg = {a, b, c};
        printf("%d", create_config(cfg, conffile));
    }
}
```